# Rss parser knows when new stuff is added

Tags: php, rss

Instead of having to check every x amount of time, is there a system that automatically updates and lets me know when something knew is pushed to the rss feed. I was told to look into webhooks and this third party zapier seems to provide exactly this service so it seems doable I'm just not sure how to go about implementing it.

Comment: Either you poll, or you get sent a notification.. No other way to do it really. Depending on the source you might get lucky with a HEAD request

Comment: How do I get sent a notification ?